# Table doesn't creates with default value [SQLalchemy]

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have table

```
users = Table(
    "users",
    metadata,

    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("username", String(32), unique=True),
    Column("password", String(64)),
    Column("games_all", Integer, default=0),
    Column("games_won", Integer, default=0),
    Column("created_at", DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
)
```

and when i do

```
metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

the table is created but with an empty default field.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCSh1.png)

I want the table to be created with the default values that I specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `default` argument is the default value set on the Python side when creating a `users` instance. If you want the default value to be set on the database side, use [`server_default`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/defaults.html#server-invoked-ddl-explicit-default-expressions).